# Total height of the page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the total height of a page using JavaScript so I can check if the page is long enough to display something, however in my testing I am unable to get the total height of a page.

I've looked around on the Internet but things like this don't seem to be well documented, as all I can find is `scrollHeight`, which, as I might mention, doesn't work.

Any way to use JavaScript to find it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Without a framework:

```
var _docHeight = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;
var _docWidth = (document.width !== undefined) ? document.width : document.body.offsetWidth;
```

Comment: This does not seem to always work, e.g. at https://www.shortgull.app/ it returns 1329 but the actual height is greater

Comment: according to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight it returns the viewport's height if applied to root element

Answer (score 16):

`document.documentElement.scrollHeight` is working ok for me in the latest version of Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: scrollHeight will give you the height of the page including stuff you need to scroll to see. offsetHeight will give you the height of the visible window content area.

Comment: and `offsetHeight` does not contain borders, margins and padding.

Comment: what is the unit of the value this returns?

Comment: in latest chrome this is giving me the height of the viewport, not the total content height

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried `$(document).height();` ?

Demo [here](http://pastebin.me/4a52303ca45de)

Comment: works for me http://pastebin.me/4a52303ca45de - make sure you have the firefox+firebug console open

Comment: This feature is obsolete, use instead `document.body.clientHeight`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/height

Answer (score 3):

Height of entire page...

```
document.body.offsetHeight
```

Height of viewport...

```
var h,
de = document.documentElement;

if (self.innerHeight) {h = window.innerHeight;}
else if (de && de.clientHeight) {h = de.clientHeight;}
else if (document.body) {h = document.body.clientHeight;}
```

[This article](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) may help you.

Answer (score 2):

To find the **height of the entire document** you could just find the highest DOM Node on current page with a simple recursion:

```
;(function() {
    var pageHeight = 0;

    function findHighestNode(nodesList) {
        for (var i = nodesList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (nodesList[i].scrollHeight && nodesList[i].clientHeight) {
                var elHeight = Math.max(nodesList[i].scrollHeight, nodesList[i].clientHeight);
                pageHeight = Math.max(elHeight, pageHeight);
            }
            if (nodesList[i].childNodes.length) findHighestNode(nodesList[i].childNodes);
        }
    }

    findHighestNode(document.documentElement.childNodes);

    // The entire page height is found
    console.log('Page height is', pageHeight);
})();
```

NOTE: It is working with `Iframes`.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use the position of an element at the bottom of the page, like:

```
$("#footer").offset().top
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS). One of the supported methods: height, innerHeight, outerHeight may be suitable for you.