# How to get the height of the overall page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried:

```
$(document).height();

$("#body").height();
```

but it make doesn't give an exact value.

Comment: What do you mean "exact"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Total height of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087920/total-height-of-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the scroll height property

```js
var el = document.body;
console.log(el.scrollHeight); // height with overflow
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.div {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Baao it works.that was what i want

Answer (score -1):

Check out the specs for the [height function](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
// Returns height of browser viewport
$( window ).height();

// Returns height of HTML document
$( document ).height();
```

The "height of the overall page" I interpret to be the size of the [viewport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport). If you're looking for something a little more robust...

```
function getPageHeight ()
{
  //If the content is smaller than the viewport, return the height
  //of the screen. Otherwise, return the height of the content.
  return Math.max ($(window).height (), $('body').height ());
}
```